# Create an array of different Id´s with the Id that are POST´ed in a select

Tags: php

I have a `SELECT name="idproduct"` inside a FORM and its OPTION VALUE is the Id of the product that I have SELECTED.   I would like to make an array in PHP with the Id´s of the products that I have SELECTED one after another.
EXAMPLE:

```
$idproducts=(1, 2, 14, 24, 8)
```

On the top of the table I have the SELECT and first I choose one product.  Then I choose another one etc....    I need the Id´s of the choosen products in that select because down the page I have a table where I want to show the products I have selected at the top.

```
$sql='SELECT    id_product,
        nameproduct,
        situation,
        quantity            
        FROM product
        WHERE id_product = "'.$idproducts.'"';
```

Somebody would explain me how can I make the array with the posted Id´s of the `SELECT`?

Comment: Do you have more than one `SELECT`, or does your one `SELECT` support multiple selections? Because if not, your `SELECT`'s value can only be one ID. If so, let's see the HTML code for the `SELECT` elements, or what are their `name=""`s

Comment: if it is a multi select one, surely this posts the values as an array?

Comment: you need array formation in javascript or php?

Comment: <?php
      $db->query("SELECT id_producto, nombreproducto FROM producto order by nombreproducto asc");
      echo "<option value=''>Elegir una opción";
      while($nombreproducto = $db->next()) {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $nombreproducto['id_producto'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['nombreproducto'] == $nombreproducto['id_producto']) echo 'SELECTED';?>><?php echo $nombreproducto['nombreproducto'];?></option>
      <?php } 
      ?>

Comment: Here is where I want to create and array with the selected products But rememeber they are choosen one by one... $sql3='SELECT producto.id_producto,
    producto.nombreproducto,
    producto.codinterno,
    producto.localizacion,
    producto.cantidad
    FROM producto
    WHERE producto.id_producto IN ????

Answer (score 1):

$sql='SELECT id_product, nameproduct, situation, quantity
        FROM product WHERE id_product IN (.$idproducts.)';

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `<select>` is multi select, you could loop through the array like so to build the query string:

```
$sql='SELECT id_product,
        nameproduct,
        situation,
        quantity            
        FROM product
        WHERE 1';

foreach( $_POST['idproducts'] as $k=>$v ){
    $sql .= ' OR id_product = ' . $v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.   The select I am using is not a multi select, because I want to choose the products one by one. I want to create and array but with the POSTED ID´s that are choosen one by one.   So the array has to be made with the incoming ID that I select at the top of the page.

Comment: Gotchya. So how do you end up with multiple incoming IDs? Do multiple `SELECT`s exist?

Answer (score 0):

If $idproducts is an array:

```
$sql='SELECT id_product, nameproduct, situation, quantity FROM product 
      WHERE id_product IN ('.implode(',',$idproducts).')';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.... But $idproducts is not an array. The Id of the product comes one by one.  First I select one product and I POST it. Then I choose a different one and I POST it again and so on...  So the ID comes one by one.   I would like to create and array with the POSTED ID´s but  one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I like to use to turn arrays of data in to or based where queries.

```
    $sql_stub = "SELECT id_product, nameproduct, situation, quantity FROM product";
    $sql = orQuery($sql_stub, array("id1", "id2"), "id_product");

    function orQuery($sql_stub, $array, $field){

        //START WHERE CLAUSE
        $where = "WHERE ";

        //ADD DATA TO THE WHERE CLAUSE
        foreach($array as $data){
                    $where = $where." ".$field." = '".$data."' OR ";
        }

        //CHECK THAT THE WHERE CLAUSE IS MORE THAN JUST WHERE
        if($where!="WHERE "){
            //REMOVE THE TRAILING OR
            $where = substring($where, strlen($where)-4);

            //APPEND TO SQL_STUB
            $sql_stub = $sql_stub.$where;
        }
        return $sql_stub;
    }
```